# My jQuery is not working

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $(".button1").click(function ()
    {
      $("p").hide("slow");
    });
    $(".button2").click(function ()
    {
      $("p").show("slow");
    });
  });
    </script>  
     </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" class="button1"/>
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" class="button2"/><h2>Welcome to F5 Technologies </h2>
  <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp F5 Technologies is a rapidly developing company, acquiring its position on the business market,
  Our company helps make products 
     delivery more effective, efficient, and meaningful to our customers, and allow them to take greater 
     responsibility for their own new products.Software is developed by  the most experienced development staffs.   </p>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the jQuery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the jQuery library itself:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

You can also include it from a [CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You should add the type="" attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

Despite my comment on the question, it looks like the main culprit is that you aren't actually referencing the jQuery JS file. Try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```